Options to enforce transitive routing in 3 peered VPCs in AWS
To start this off, this is strictly a test scenario that I'm playing with, I know transitive peering is not allowed but I would still like to know what technical workarounds are possible to enforce transitive peering in a situation like this.
Main problem:
We have three VPCs that have VPC Peering like this VPC A (10.10.0.0/16) <--> VPC B (10.20.0.0/16) <--> VPC C (10.30.0.0/16). We have clients in VPC A that need to reach Servers in VPC C and some more specific requirements mentioned below.
Main requirements:

VPCs need to be peered as mentioned above.
Transit Gateway must not be used.
Internet traffic needs to go out only via VPC B with with either a NAT Gateway or Internet Gateway.

In VPC B, I have setup all necessary components, NAT Gateway, Internet GW, NAT Instance. In all VPCs, I have setup the necessary Route Tables, Network ACLs, Security Groups and Peerings.
Closest "solution" I could dig information and come up with is using an EC2 instance to do NAT in VPC B in the private subnet, to do all the NATing/routing and pointing the necessary traffic to where it needs to go. This, if I'm not misatken means to set that NAT/Router instance in all the other EC2 instances (VPC A and VPC C) as a default gateway but still wondering if I'm diging on the wrong direction.
I have been trying to find solutions but to no definitive workarounds as of yet. I would imensely appreciate any input or guiding in the right direction?
Tried so far to setup in the Client machines(VPC A) the default gateway (Amazon Linux 2023) using the comand "route add feault gw x.x.x.x" so that traffic going out of the instance as a next hop in the VPC B NAT/Router instance but I'm getting an error that that network is not reachable, which I guess is expected? I'm still trying to set the default gw using a secondary interface but wondering whether the AWS VPC intrinsic router (x.x.x.1) will understand what I'm trying to do even if I somehow achieve setting this up.
Has anyone had a similiar situation. I know these limitations are in place for a good reason but I believe there still should be a technical workaround on a Network level.
